# How can I get product simple qty in cart?

Tags: product, cart, configurable-product, qty-increment

I am trying to get quantity of simple products in the cart but it only returns the configurable quantity.

How can I get product simple qty in cart?

I am using this:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();

foreach ($cart->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if($item->getProduct()->getData('type_id') == 'simple'){
            $theqty = $this->escapeHtml($item->getQty());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't really said what you want to get, and your example doesn't really help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, this should do what you need, you don't need to access the product object, and it's only the price you'd need from the configurable product line in the quote.

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$valor = [];

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ('simple' != $item->getProductType()) continue;
        $valor[]= array (
                'id' => $item->getSku(),
                'quantity' => $item->getQty(),
                'price' => $item->getParentItemId() ? $item->getParentItem()->getPrice() : $item->getPrice()
        );
}

$valor_json = json_encode($valor);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$ids = array();

foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
        $preco = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $theqty = $this->escapeHtml($item->getQty());
        if($item->getProduct()->getData('type_id') == 'configurable'){
            $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $valor .= '{ id: "'.$sku->getSku().'", price:'.$preco.', quantity: '.$theqty .'},';
            $sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
        }elseif($item->getProduct()->getData('type_id') == 'simple'){
            if (!(in_array($sku, $ids))) {
                $valor .= '{ id: "'.$sku.'", price:'.$preco.', quantity: '.$theqty .'},';
            }
        }
        array_push($ids, $sku);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$cart->getAllItems()` to get the simple items too.

Comment: Hey Fabian, [getAllItems](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L755) is a subset of [getItemsCollection](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L738). It just excludes items where `->isDeleted()` is true

Comment: Nothing change, but i try something here thats work, now i need get the sku of configurable products, in cart "$sku = $item->getSku();" only return the simple sku.

Answer (score 1):

You can get product quantity without looping all items:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get product quantity without looping all items:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
$qty = $_item->getQty();
```